# Slider banner with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone explain to me how to make an image slider with JavaScript only (not jQuery)?

I have found many questions addressing this issue, but have had difficulty understanding the answers and haven't been able to make the solutions work.  I have sliders in my project, but they are not animated.  Instead, they are an image that changes every three seconds.  I would like the images to slide to the left every three seconds.  Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to achieve this?

My HTML:

```
<div class="eight columns all">
    <img id="img-slide">
    <!--<p>>></p> -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#img-slide{
    margin:15px;
    height: 95%;
    width:95%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

And the functions in JS:

```
function slide1(){
    document.getElementById('img-slide').src="img/slide_1.jpg";
    setTimeout("slide2()", 2500);
}

function slide2(){
    document.getElementById('img-slide').src="img/slide_2.jpg";
    setTimeout("slide3()", 3000);
}

function slide3(){
    document.getElementById('img-slide').src="img/slide_3.jpg";
    setTimeout("slide1()", 3000);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Work out some logic steps for the javascript code first, then look up how to do those steps, attempt to implement it, then when it breaks post a question. So it doesn't look like you are asking for a tutorial (which isn't allowed on SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've redone your logic to show the images, note that I am not pro with css, the result is almost what you wanted, the image exit to the left but the new image come from the left too, you might want to tweak the css to make it work like you want.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/n1r0dw74/6/)

Here is the html:

```
<div class="eight columns all slider">
    <img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="hide">
    <img src="http://images.medicaldaily.com/sites/medicaldaily.com/files/2013/08/04/0/62/6259.jpg" class="hide">
    <img src="http://animalia-life.com/data_images/wallpaper/bunny/bunny-01.jpg" class="hide">
</div>
```

Now there is one img per image, note the added class slider to the div

Now for the js, I take all img inside slider, calculate the last image to show and the first, then add/remove show/hide class to the correct elements.

```
//This is the latest img, it will serve to know wich img to hide
var old = listPict.length - 1;
//This will represent the current img to show
var current = 0;

//The timeout will recall this function every 3 sec
function loop() {
    //We set the class of the current img to show
    listPict[current].setAttribute('class', 'show');
    //We hide the last img
    listPict[old].setAttribute('class', 'hide');

    //Update the variables !
    old = current;
    current++;

    //If the current is bigger then the list of images, return to 0
    if (current === listPict.length)
        current = 0;

    //Recall every 3 sec
    //Note that we don't put () because we don't want to execute it right away
    setTimeout(loop, 3000);
}

loop();
```

Now we need to add the css to make the transition work !

```
<!-- I added position: absolute; -->
<!-- This allow me to use left -->
.slider img{
    margin:15px;
    height: 95%;
    width:95%;
    border-radius:5px;    
    position: absolute;
}

<!-- This show the current image with a transition -->
<!-- It replace the left attribute to 0 and the opacity to 1 -->
.slider img.show{
    opacity:1;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;

}

<!-- This hide the current image with a transition -->
<!-- It move the image to the left and the opacity to 0 -->
.slider img.hide{
    left: -1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think if you get confuesd with logic and want a very easy way to work with image slider you should use bootstrap .well i'm gonna give you an example buddy.
Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites.
Bootstrap is completely free to download and use!

**Carousel Plugin**

The Carousel plugin is a component for cycling through elements, like a carousel (slideshow).

**How To Create a Carousel**

The following example shows how to create a basic carousel:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope that help you

Comment: The question states that they do not want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that in an easy way, but if there is many banners, them it get's more bigger.

```js
let currentBanner;
currentBanner ? currentBanner = currentBanner : currentBanner = 1;

function changeBanner() {
  const banner1 = document.getElementById('banner1');
  const banner2 = document.getElementById('banner2');
  const banner3 = document.getElementById('banner3')
  if (currentBanner == 1) {
    banner1.style.display = 'none'
    banner2.style.display = 'block'
    currentBanner++
  } else if (currentBanner == 2) {
    banner2.style.display = 'none'
    banner3.style.display = 'block'
    currentBanner++
  } else if (currentBanner == 3) {
    banner3.style.display = 'none'
    banner1.style.display = 'block'
    currentBanner = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex item" style="margin: 4vw 6vw 0vw 6vw; position: relative;"> 
       <input id="banner2" class="banners" active="true" style="display: none" type="image" src=path></input>
       <input id="banner3" class="banners" active="true" style="display: none" type="image" src=path></input>
       <input id="banner1" class="banners" active="false" type="image" src=path></input>
</div>
```