# Background Images (CSS) wont show up on site

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything but my background image wont show up

the image was in images folder

I have my file linked into CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Also have the following lines on html

```
<div id="bgImage" class="bgImageClass">
    
    </div>
```

Meanwhile in style.css

```
.bgImageClass {

 background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');

}
#bgImage { 
    position:absolute; width:300px; height:250px;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

I hope someone can help

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the other styles working on the website? are you style.css is loading and the path is correctly defined ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes other styles are working so my style.css is correctly defined

Comment: Open the `Network` tab in your browser's developer tools and check for errors. Check the address you're trying to load the image from.

Comment: Check the img src `(url)` i bet that wrongs. otherwise i do not see any reason why not loading

Comment: Are the `images` and `css` folders in the same location? If not, you might want to change the path to something like `../../images/background.jpg` (add an extra `..`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these CSS styles to show background image.

```css
.bgImageClass {
    background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position:absolute; width:300px; height:250px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgImage" class="bgImageClass"></div>
```

Comment: can you tell me on how can i put another image in front of that? thanks

Comment: because i want to create a banner with transitions using only css and js without using keyframes

Comment: @CarloBarrogo you can create image sprite or stack of images & show them conditionally by some time interval using javascript.

Comment: can you share some codes or tips? It would be a great help. Thank you

Comment: @CarloBarrogo You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784647/slider-banner-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Mix all of those properties in **class selector or id selector** as follow :

```
.bgImageClass { 
         background-image: url('../../image/background.jpg'); 
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
position:absolute; 
width:300px; 
height:250px; 
transition: opacity 0.5s; 
   }
```